# How to have enumerate function cycles through the data multiple times

Tags: python, cycle, enumerate

I want this set of code to run every time a line contains CAFE. Currently, it only runs for the first time CAFE appears. I think I need to change the index inside of the enumerate function from dataset to something that specifies that the code will begin counting value for i again after each line that contains CAFE.

```py
with open('data.txt', 'r') as dataset:
    for line in dataset:
        if 'CAFE' in line:
             for i, line in enumerate(dataset):
                 if i > 1 and i < 130 and i %2 == 0:
                     print(line)

                 else:
                    pass
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: are you sure that dataset contains more than a line? Try printing dataset

Comment: Could you explain better what you need to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you enter the first loop, you'll be traversed to 1st line in text file.

In the first iteration, when the second loop iterates through all lines, the dataset object points to EOF(end of file). 
So after 1st iteration, you'll be reached EOF. That's the reason it only runs for the first time.

Instead, you can store all lines in a list and then perform your process on the list.

Code:

```
data = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as dataset:
    for line in dataset:
        data.append(line)

for line in data:
    if 'CAFE' in line:
         for i, lt in enumerate(data):
             if i > 1 and i < 130 and i %2 == 0:
                 print(lt)
             else:
                pass
    else:
        pass
```

And one more thing to notice is you've named the variable as "line" in both the for loops which is a bad practice.

Comment: Strange thank you! Unfortunately when I run that code I don't get an error message, but nothing is printed...

Comment: Yes, you won't receive any error messages. You can think this dataset variable as a pointer, where it points at the first line at the start and every time you traverse in loop the pointer comes down to EOF and stays there thats why on second iteration of outer for loop there exists nothing in datset variable hence the loop breaks out. Please accept answer if you got your answer :)

Comment: Strange thank you! Unfortunately I get the same result with your code as I did with mine. It is only exporting the values for the first CAFE line and not for the others following it.